# Notification service Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I tried to start background service to get notifications in CodenameOne,service started using LocationManger but notifications are not displayed in tablets and it was worked for mobiles with version 5 and above.Is there any other way to start the service in codenameOne to get the notifications,and it must be work on android and ios tablets with versions also.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't much of a description it's a bit hard to tell but it could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/0e023517ce438c0e94a0e258941287c3c33140f9) that was just fixed.

It should be in the build servers sometime this week.